# Sum of concave and strictly concave functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can I prove, for the general case, that the sum of a concave and a strictly concave function, yields a strictly concave function?

Comment: The definition of concavity should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\color{blue}f$ concave, $\color{olive}g$ strictly concave, $t \in ]0,1[$

\begin{align}
\color{blue}f(tx+(1-t)y)\,+\,\color{olive}g(tx+(1-t)y) &\color{blue}\geq t\color{blue}f(x)+(1-t)\color{blue}f(y)\,+\,\color{olive}g(tx+(1-t)y) \\ &\color{olive}> t\color{blue}f(x)+(1-t)\color{blue}f(y)\,+\, t\color{olive}g(x)+(1-t)\color{olive}g(y) \\ &= t(\color{blue}f(x)+\color{olive}g(x))\,+\,(1-t)(\color{blue}f(y)+\color{olive}g(y))
\end{align}

...